# NSIS Uninstall Feedback Dialog with Radio Buttons

Tags: user-interface, nsis, uninstallation, feedback

I am trying to show a simple dialog before uninstall in NSIS. It consists of several predefined radio buttons (reasons for uninstalling), none of them checked initially. Uninstallation cannot continue until a user selects one of the radio buttons.

As a bonus, ideally I would like to have a custom reason text field too (toggle-able via last radio button). As well as 2 more text fields for custom text and email.

Then I need to take selected value(s) (checked radio button) as well as text fields data and either append it to my predefined URL to which I make a GET request using InetC or similar plugin before uninstaller exits; or laternatively construct a POST request to a predefined URL using InetC or similar plugin. I cannot figure out how to create such a dialog page. Any help would be appreciated.

What I am looking for:

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 1):

First, you should get familiar with [nsDialogs](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html) to create the interface according to your needs. Since nsDialogs is a function, you would then can call it as a [custom page](https://github.com/NSIS-Dev/Documentation/blob/master/Reference/Page.md).

Answer (score 1):

You can use my tool **Visual & Installer** (www.visual-installer.com) for Visual Studio 2005 - 2015 to fast write the NSIS code.

(If you are "writing" the installer - I assume you have some experiences with nsDialogs).

Also there are some other tools like **NSIS Dialog Designer** (http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=329801) which can help you and generate lot of code for you.

This tool is GUI based - designer similar to Visual Studio designer - but remember: the result is still the scripts!